# Add server with existing data as DataNode to Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I need to build distributed fail proof (as possible) cluster from several servers with existing data.
I'm new to Hadoop, but as far as I can tell, it more close to satisfy my requirements than other products.
The problem is that I already some data (quite large files) which I want to be available in Hadoop.
Is it possible to add server with existing data as DataNode to Hadoop?
What should I do to make it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be impossible, except for moving existing data to HDFS after deploying DataNode on that box